# Shiny-Server Log - Fails to change ownership

Tags: ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server, chown

I am running a shiny-server on Ubuntu:
Shiny-Server Version: v1.5.12.933

I changed my configuration such that the server is running as non-root user "shiny".

Now the log file \var\log\shiny-server.log shows the following error:

> [2020-04-16T10:15:38.908] [ERROR] shiny-server - Error attempting to change ownership of log file at /var/log/shiny-server/shinyApp-shiny-20200416-101538-36957.log: EPERM: operation not permitted, fchown

The directory of the log files has the follwing permissions:

> drwxrwx--- 2 shiny shiny-apps 4096 Apr 16 11:01 shiny-server

(The user shiny is also member of the group shiny-apps)

Since I changed this setting, no more logs have been created in this directory.
Have I forgotten any other settings?

Best regards

Comment: In Unix and Unix-like systems, and Linux, too, they are called "directories" and not "folders" which is a Windows-ism and not the same thing.

Comment: My bad sorry, I edited the text :)